# ASIHTTPRequest import issue

Tags: iphone, http, import, asihttprequest

I am trying to get up and running with ASIHTTPRequest.  I have followed the instructions as per http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions, having added the classes to a new group called ASIHTTPRequest and added the binaries.  However when I try to add the imports, I get import errors on the .m files:

```
#import "ASIAuthenticationDialog.h"
#import "ASIAuthenticationDialog.m"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "Reachability.m"
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I am new to Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not import `.m` files only header files `.h`